# Optimizing building placement

Tags: algorithm, plane

Let's assume we have a finite plane that consists of a grid (imagine a shape that consists of square planes divided into smaller square fields - see attached image. The big squares must always be connected with some other square by their side). Now, let's also assume that we have a collection of non-unique buildings, of which every has its size (which indicates how many square fields it takes on the grid), its shape and its "type" (like A, B, C) which it delivers/produces over time. There is also a special (fourth) type of building, that influences other buildings, making their production faster. It also has its size, and shape but it also has a unique attribute of, let's call it, "influence range" - it's a number of small squares that it influences. Every building that is in this range would get a percentage boost to its production (dependent on the size of this boosting building), up to 100%. I'm looking for an algorithm/approach that would be optimizing the location of all the given buildings in respect to the given production type (ideally also in respect to any combination of them). So like, given a grid of given shape, a collection of specific buildings and a given type create a proposition of placement that would create an optimal production of this type.

Example images:

[image: grid example]
[image: example positioning]

I thought about creating all the permutations of possible placements and choosing the best one but I guess that this could quickly become a lot and would be quite sub-optimal. This also makes it really hard to take the shape of possible area to consideration. I also found some papers about building placements but in RTS games and this is not the case as there are no bounds in those examples.

Is there any class of algorithms tacklings this particular problem? How would you approach it? I would be super grateful for some code examples as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would be shocked if this is not an NP-hard problem, as it has the same properties as bin-packing but with more complexity. 

To start I'd suggest a simple BFS between all possible states, with as much pruning as possible (possibly A*.)